# Glm rotate object by time

Tags: opengl, rotation, glfw, glm-math

I have an object which I want to rotate on key hold using this function

```
if (key == GLFW_KEY_S && action == GLFW_REPEAT) {
            timer = glfwGetTime();
}
```

Which sends `timer` to this rotation

```
auto rotateMat = rotate(mat4{}, timer * 0.4f, {0, 1, 0});
```

But problem is, I hold key `S` pressed and the object is rotating but when I release it, time is changing of course, since `glfwGetTime()` gets real time. Then I press `S` again and hold it to rotate, but it starts rotation from different object angle as when it stopped. Any ideas how to fix it?

**EDIT:**

I have fixed it by using
`timer += 0.1;`

But when I press `S` and hold it, it has a delay about 1 second until the object starts rotating. It was same with using real `glfwGetTime()`. How can I have no delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should track if the key is pressed:

```
if (action == GLFM_PRESS) {
    keysPressed[key] = true;
}
if (action == GLFM_RELEASE) {
    keysPressed[key] = false;
}
```

In the render loop:

```
now = glfwGetTime();
double delta = now - lastTime;
lastTime = now;

if (keysPressed[GLFW_KEY_S]) {
    timer += delta;
}
if (keysPressed[GLFW_KEY_A]) {
    timer -= delta;
}
auto rotateMat = rotate(mat4{}, timer * 0.4f, {0, 1, 0});
```

Comment: Thank you, delay is fixed but since I want to rotate left, right, up and down, I do `pressedLastTick = -glfwGetTime();` in case of rotation to other side and this does not work well, since I am subtracting the time value. How can I avoid it?

Comment: I have rewritte the answer to take into account multiple keys.